# Removing an ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation instance from an array based on an attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My rails app is pulling `@locations` data into an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` array.

```
@locations 
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Location id: 10, organization_id: 2, name: "Quitzonville", ...
```

I would like to remove an instance based on the `:name` attribute, but I also need to apply the `.arrange_serializable` method after.

So far, I've tried:

```
@locations.select { |loc| loc[:name] != ... }
```

method, but I can't seem to apply `.arrange_serializable` after...

Could someone offer some suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could accomplish what you want by using a `.where.not` query.
`.select` transforms the `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` into an `Array`. `where.not` will keep it as an `AssociationRelation`. So your code might look like:

```
@locations.where.not(name: bad_names).arrange_serializable
```

Where `bad_names` is either a single name you don't want included, or an array of names you don't want included.